# Middleware no me deja consumir api

Tags: php, laravel, api, function, middleware

Estoy consumiendo una api con laravel 9.2, todo funciona bien, consigo las respuestas y todo, pero al agregar los middlewares me da el siguiente error= "Call to a member function getCoverge() on null" , mi funcion 'getCoverge()' esta en un archivo .php dentro de una carpeta llamada 'services' en la carpeta /app.

los middlewares los estoy agregando en los controladores

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }
```

cuando quito los middlewares todo vuelve a funcionar correctamente, no entiendo bien que pasa, me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Si le asignas el middleware a las rutas pasa lo mismo?

Comment: no! no pasa lo mismo, ya funciona! muchas gracias, no probé porque creía que era lo mismo, pero eso funciono, muchas gracias